# Why $\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\sin\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)}{\frac{1}{x}} = 0$?

Tags: limits

I thought it would be like this:

$$\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\sin\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)}{\frac{1}{x}} = 1$$

but wolfram didn't show me the answer I was expecting(

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Because as $x\to 0$, you have $\frac 1x\to \pm\infty$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can write your limit in the form
$$
\lim_{x\to 0}{x\sin(1/x)}
$$
Now note that
$$
|x\sin(1/x)|\le|x|,
$$
so if $x$ approches zero, then $x\sin(1/x)$ goes to zero too.